# Why pandas does not want to subset given columns in a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove certain values with that code, however pandas does not give me to, instead outputs

```
ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 10: given 2
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Volumes/SSD/IT/DataSets/Automobile_data.csv")
print(df.shape)
columns_df  = ['index', 'company', 'body-style', 'wheel-base', 'length', 'engine-type',
       'num-of-cylinders', 'horsepower', 'average-mileage', 'price']
prohibited_symbols = ['?','Nan''n.a']
df = df[df[columns_df] != prohibited_symbols]
print(df)
```

Comment: You may want [pandas.DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = df[~df[columns_df].str.contains('|'.join(prohibited_symbols))]
```

The regex operator '|' helps remove records that contain any of your prohibited symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you are trying is not doing what you imagine it should.
`df = df[df[columns_df] != prohibited_symbols]`
Above line will always return False values for everything. You can't iterate over a list of prohibited symbols like that. `!=` will do only a simple inequality check and none of your cells will be equal to the list of prohibited symbols probably. Also using that syntax will not delete those values from your cells.

You'll have to use a for loop and clean every column like this.

```
for column in columns_df: 
    df[column] = df[column].str.replace('|'.join(prohibited_symbols), '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well specify the values you consider as null with the na_values argument when reading the data and then use dropna from pandas.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Volumes/SSD/IT/DataSets/Automobile_data.csv", na_values=['?','Nan''n.a'])
df = df.dropna()
```